# Reduce the Cyclomatic complexity of a function

Tags: java, refactoring, cyclomatic-complexity

I have a function which uses the JPA Criteria API to retrieve data from the database depending on some params I pass to it.
The params are passed using the object `gridParams`, as following :

```
public List<MyObjectDTO> find(final GridParamsDTO gridParams) {

        final CriteriaBuilder builder = getCriteriaBuilder();
        final List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

        final CriteriaQuery<MyObjectDTO> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(MyObjectDTO.class);

        final Root<MyObject> from = criteriaQuery.from(MyObject.class);

        Join<MyObject, AnotherObject> join = from.join(MyObject_.anotherObject, JoinType.LEFT);

        if ((gridParams.getFilter() != null) && (gridParams.getFilter().length > 0)) {

            for (final GridFilterDTO filter : gridParams.getFilter()) {
                if ("fieldX".equals(filter.getField())) {
                    final List<Predicate> sqPredicates = new ArrayList<>();
                    Subquery<Long> sq = criteriaQuery.subquery(Long.class);
                    Root<ObjectX> sqFrom = sq.from(ObjectX.class);
                    sqPredicates
                            .add(builder.equal(sqFrom.get(ObjectX_.organismeIDE), filter.getFilterSingleValue()));
                    sq.select(sqFrom.get(ObjectX_.referentielID).get(MyObject_.objectX));
                    sq.where(builder.and(sqPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[sqPredicates.size()])));
                    predicates.add(builder.in(from.get(MyObject_.objectX)).value(sq));
                }
                if ("fieldA".equals(filter.getField()) || "fieldB".equals(filter.getField())) {
                    final GridFilterOperatorEnum gridFilterEnumValues = GridFilterOperatorEnum.values()[filter.getOperator().ordinal()];
                    switch (gridFilterEnumValues) {
                    case TEXT_CONTAINS:
                        predicates.add(builder.like(builder.upper(from.get(filter.getField())), "%" + filter.getFilterSingleValue().toUpperCase() + "%"));
                        break;
                    case TEXT_START_WITH:
                        predicates.add(builder.like(builder.upper(from.get(filter.getField())), filter.getFilterSingleValue().toUpperCase() + "%"));
                        break;
                    case TEXT_DIFFERENT:
                        predicates.add(builder.notEqual(from.get(filter.getField()), filter.getFilterSingleValue()));
                        break;
                    case TEXT_END_WITH:
                        predicates.add(builder.like(builder.upper(from.get(filter.getField())), "%" + filter.getFilterSingleValue().toUpperCase()));
                        break;
                    case TEXT_EQUALS:
                        predicates.add(builder.equal(builder.upper(from.get(filter.getField())), filter.getFilterSingleValue().toUpperCase()));
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if ("dateField1".equals(filter.getField()) || "dateField2".equals(filter.getField())) {
                    final GridFilterOperatorEnum gridFilterEnumValues = GridFilterOperatorEnum.values()[filter.getOperator().ordinal()];
                    switch (gridFilterEnumValues) {
                    case DATE_EQUALS:
                        predicates.add(builder.equal(from.<LocalDate> get(filter.getField()), LocalDate.parse(filter.getFilterSingleValue())));
                        break;
                    case DATE_BEFORE:
                        predicates.add(builder.lessThan(from.<LocalDate> get(filter.getField()), LocalDate.parse(filter.getFilterSingleValue())));
                        break;
                    case DATE_AFTER:
                        predicates.add(builder.greaterThan(from.<LocalDate> get(filter.getField()), LocalDate.parse(filter.getFilterSingleValue())));
                        break;
                    case DATE_BETWEEN:
                        predicates.add(
                                builder.between(from.<LocalDate> get(filter.getField()), LocalDate.parse(filter.getFilterSetValues()[0]),
                                        LocalDate.parse(filter.getFilterSetValues()[1])));
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if ("anotherField".equals(filter.getField())) {
                    if (filter.getFilterSetValues().length > 0) {
                        predicates
                                .add(builder.isTrue(join.get(AnotherObject_.lib).in((Object[]) filter.getFilterSetValues())));
                    } else {
                        predicates.add(join.get(AnotherObject_.lib).isNull());
                    }

                }
            }

        }

        if (gridParams.hasSort()) {
            List<Order> orderList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (IGridSort gridSort : gridParams.getSort()) {
                if (ArrayUtils.contains(new String[] { "fieldA", "dateField1", "dateField2", "fieldB" }, gridSort.getField())) {
                    if (gridSort.getSort().equalsIgnoreCase(GridSortDTO.ASC)) {
                        orderList.add(builder.asc(from.get(gridSort.getField())));
                    } else if (gridSort.getSort().equalsIgnoreCase(GridSortDTO.DESC)) {
                        orderList.add(builder.desc(from.get(gridSort.getField())));
                    }
                }
                if (gridSort.getField().equalsIgnoreCase("anotherField")) {
                    if (gridSort.getSort().equalsIgnoreCase(GridSortDTO.ASC)) {
                        orderList.add(builder.asc(join.get(AnotherObject_.lib)));
                    } else if (gridSort.getSort().equalsIgnoreCase(GridSortDTO.DESC)) {
                        orderList.add(builder.desc(join.get(AnotherObject_.lib)));
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!orderList.isEmpty()) {
                criteriaQuery.orderBy(orderList);
            }
        }

        predicates.add(builder.between(builder.literal(LocalDate.now()), from.get(MyObject_.dateDebut),
                from.get(MyObject_.dateFin)));

        criteriaQuery.multiselect(from.get(MyObject_.objectX), from.get(MyObject_.dateDebut), from.get(MyObject_.dateFin),
                from.get(MyObject_.lib), from.get(MyObject_.coleur), join,
                from.get(MyObject_.refExterne));
        criteriaQuery.where(builder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()])));
        criteriaQuery.distinct(true);

        final TypedQuery<MyObjectDTO> typedQuery = getEntityManager().createQuery(criteriaQuery);

        if (gridParams.hasStart()) {
            typedQuery.setFirstResult(gridParams.getStartRow());
        }
        if (gridParams.hasEnd()) {
            typedQuery.setMaxResults(gridParams.getEndRow() - Math.max(0, gridParams.getStartRow()));
        }

        return typedQuery.getResultList();
    }
}
```

The problem is that SonarQube complains that The Cyclomatic Complexity of this method "find" is 31 which is greater than 30 authorized, I did some researches and I found that I have to refactor my function in order to reduce the Cyclomatic Complexity.

In this function I have to test if the `gridParams` has 4 fields  defined : (start, end, sort and filter), the sort and filter are object arrays so I have to iterate over them.

Ultimately I need to check a lot of fields and I cannot see how this can be done without lots of checks :/

How can I solve this in my case ?

Comment: At first glance, you need to get rid of deep `if-else` hierarchy to fix it quickly.

Comment: This method is bloated up, so to get rid of the sonar issue, just split the method up into smaller methods

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to start by looking at some of the refactorings from the [Refactoring Catalog](https://refactoring.com/catalog/).

If you look at your method, you have a number of sections:

- the section where the predicate list is compiled
- the section where the order list is compiled
- the section where the query is created
- the section where the query is run

These are good candidates for refactoring into separate methods using the Extract Method refactoring. Once these sections have been extracted to new methods, the process can be repeated on each method until you think you have gone as far as you can. Then, you can look at the new methods you have created and identify those methods that manipulate the same data. They are likely to want to be moved to a separate class, for example, a Query class.

The switch statements also look like good candidates for the Replace Conditional with Polymorphism refactoring.

If in doubt, start really small and do one simple refactoring at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you may extract methods:

```
public List<MyObjectDTO> find(final GridParamsDTO gridParams) {
    final CriteriaBuilder builder = getCriteriaBuilder();

    final CriteriaQuery<MyObjectDTO> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(MyObjectDTO.class);
    final Root<MyObject> from = criteriaQuery.from(MyObject.class);
    final Join<MyObject, AnotherObject> join = from.join(MyObject_.anotherObject, JoinType.LEFT);

    final List<Order> orderList = buildOrderList(gridParams, builder, from, join);
    if (!orderList.isEmpty()) {
        criteriaQuery.orderBy(orderList);
    }

    criteriaQuery.multiselect(from.get(MyObject_.objectX),
                              from.get(MyObject_.dateDebut),
                              from.get(MyObject_.dateFin),
                              from.get(MyObject_.lib),
                              from.get(MyObject_.coleur),
                              join,
                              from.get(MyObject_.refExterne));
    criteriaQuery.where(builder.and(buildPredicates(gridParams, builder, criteriaQuery, from, join)));
    criteriaQuery.distinct(true);

    final TypedQuery<MyObjectDTO> typedQuery = getEntityManager().createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    if (gridParams.hasStart()) {
        typedQuery.setFirstResult(gridParams.getStartRow());
    }
    if (gridParams.hasEnd()) {
        typedQuery.setMaxResults(gridParams.getEndRow() - Math.max(0, gridParams.getStartRow()));
    }
    return typedQuery.getResultList();
}
```

```
private Predicate[] buildPredicates(final GridParamsDTO gridParams, final CriteriaBuilder builder,
        final CriteriaQuery<MyObjectDTO> criteriaQuery, final Root<MyObject> from,
        Join<MyObject, AnotherObject> join) {
    final List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    final GridFilterDTO[] filters = gridParams.getFilter();
    if (filters != null && filters.length > 0) {
        for (final GridFilterDTO filter : filters) {
            if ("fieldX".equals(filter.getField())) {
                addSubQuery(builder, predicates, criteriaQuery, from, filter);
            }
            if ("fieldA".equals(filter.getField()) || "fieldB".equals(filter.getField())) {
                addTextPredicates(builder, predicates, from, filter);
            }
            if ("dateField1".equals(filter.getField()) || "dateField2".equals(filter.getField())) {
                addDatePredicates(builder, predicates, from, filter);
            }
            if ("anotherField".equals(filter.getField())) {
                if (filter.getFilterSetValues().length > 0) {
                    predicates
                            .add(builder.isTrue(join.get(AnotherObject_.lib).in((Object[]) filter.getFilterSetValues())));
                } else {
                    predicates.add(join.get(AnotherObject_.lib).isNull());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    predicates.add(builder.between(builder.literal(LocalDate.now()), from.get(MyObject_.dateDebut),
            from.get(MyObject_.dateFin)));
    return predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]);
}
```

```
private void addSubQuery(final CriteriaBuilder builder, final List<Predicate> predicates,
        final CriteriaQuery<MyObjectDTO> criteriaQuery, final Root<MyObject> from, final GridFilterDTO filter) {
    final List<Predicate> sqPredicates = new ArrayList<>();
    Subquery<Long> sq = criteriaQuery.subquery(Long.class);
    Root<ObjectX> sqFrom = sq.from(ObjectX.class);
    sqPredicates.add(builder.equal(sqFrom.get(ObjectX_.organismeIDE), filter.getFilterSingleValue()));
    sq.select(sqFrom.get(ObjectX_.referentielID).get(MyObject_.objectX));
    sq.where(builder.and(sqPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[sqPredicates.size()])));
    predicates.add(builder.in(from.get(MyObject_.objectX)).value(sq));
}
```

```
private void addTextPredicates(final CriteriaBuilder builder, final List<Predicate> predicates,
        final Root<MyObject> from, final GridFilterDTO filter) {
    final GridFilterOperatorEnum gridFilterEnumValues = GridFilterOperatorEnum.values()[filter.getOperator().ordinal()];
    switch (gridFilterEnumValues) {
    case TEXT_CONTAINS:
        predicates.add(builder.like(builder.upper(from.get(filter.getField())), "%" + filter.getFilterSingleValue().toUpperCase() + "%"));
        break;
    case TEXT_START_WITH:
        predicates.add(builder.like(builder.upper(from.get(filter.getField())), filter.getFilterSingleValue().toUpperCase() + "%"));
        break;
    case TEXT_DIFFERENT:
        predicates.add(builder.notEqual(from.get(filter.getField()), filter.getFilterSingleValue()));
        break;
    case TEXT_END_WITH:
        predicates.add(builder.like(builder.upper(from.get(filter.getField())), "%" + filter.getFilterSingleValue().toUpperCase()));
        break;
    case TEXT_EQUALS:
        predicates.add(builder.equal(builder.upper(from.get(filter.getField())), filter.getFilterSingleValue().toUpperCase()));
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

```
private void addDatePredicates(final CriteriaBuilder builder, final List<Predicate> predicates,
        final Root<MyObject> from, final GridFilterDTO filter) {
    final GridFilterOperatorEnum gridFilterEnumValues = GridFilterOperatorEnum.values()[filter.getOperator().ordinal()];
    switch (gridFilterEnumValues) {
    case DATE_EQUALS:
        predicates.add(builder.equal(from.<LocalDate> get(filter.getField()), LocalDate.parse(filter.getFilterSingleValue())));
        break;
    case DATE_BEFORE:
        predicates.add(builder.lessThan(from.<LocalDate> get(filter.getField()), LocalDate.parse(filter.getFilterSingleValue())));
        break;
    case DATE_AFTER:
        predicates.add(builder.greaterThan(from.<LocalDate> get(filter.getField()), LocalDate.parse(filter.getFilterSingleValue())));
        break;
    case DATE_BETWEEN:
        predicates.add(
                builder.between(from.<LocalDate> get(filter.getField()), LocalDate.parse(filter.getFilterSetValues()[0]),
                        LocalDate.parse(filter.getFilterSetValues()[1])));
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

```
private List<Order> buildOrderList(final GridParamsDTO gridParams, final CriteriaBuilder builder,
        final Root<MyObject> from, Join<MyObject, AnotherObject> join) {
    if (gridParams.hasSort()) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    List<Order> orderList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (IGridSort gridSort : gridParams.getSort()) {
        if (ArrayUtils.contains(new String[] { "fieldA", "dateField1", "dateField2", "fieldB" }, gridSort
                .getField())) {
            if (gridSort.getSort().equalsIgnoreCase(GridSortDTO.ASC)) {
                orderList.add(builder.asc(from.get(gridSort.getField())));
            } else if (gridSort.getSort().equalsIgnoreCase(GridSortDTO.DESC)) {
                orderList.add(builder.desc(from.get(gridSort.getField())));
            }
        }
        if (gridSort.getField().equalsIgnoreCase("anotherField")) {
            if (gridSort.getSort().equalsIgnoreCase(GridSortDTO.ASC)) {
                orderList.add(builder.asc(join.get(AnotherObject_.lib)));
            } else if (gridSort.getSort().equalsIgnoreCase(GridSortDTO.DESC)) {
                orderList.add(builder.desc(join.get(AnotherObject_.lib)));
            }
        }
    }
    return orderList;
}
```

Now it is up to you to decide whether this is better.
You may even extract more methods and more local variables to avoid too much repetition in this code.

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this:

```
public List<MyObjectDTO> find(final GridParamsDTO gridParams) {

    CriteriaBuilder builder = getCriteriaBuilder();
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

    CriteriaQuery<MyObjectDTO> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(MyObjectDTO.class);

    Root<MyObject> from = criteriaQuery.from(MyObject.class);

    Join<MyObject, AnotherObject> join = from.join(MyObject_.anotherObject, JoinType.LEFT);

    predicates = subMethod1(gridParams, builder, predicates, criteriaQuery, from, join);

    criteriaQuery = subMethod2(gridParams, builder, criteriaQuery, from, join);

    predicates.add(builder.between(builder.literal(LocalDate.now()), from.get(MyObject_.dateDebut),
            from.get(MyObject_.dateFin)));

    criteriaQuery.multiselect(from.get(MyObject_.objectX), from.get(MyObject_.dateDebut), from.get(MyObject_.dateFin),
            from.get(MyObject_.lib), from.get(MyObject_.coleur), join,
            from.get(MyObject_.refExterne));
    criteriaQuery.where(builder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()])));
    criteriaQuery.distinct(true);

    final TypedQuery<MyObjectDTO> typedQuery = getEntityManager().createQuery(criteriaQuery);

    if (gridParams.hasStart()) {
        typedQuery.setFirstResult(gridParams.getStartRow());
    }
    if (gridParams.hasEnd()) {
        typedQuery.setMaxResults(gridParams.getEndRow() - Math.max(0, gridParams.getStartRow()));
    }

    return typedQuery.getResultList();
}

private CriteriaQuery<MyObjectDTO> subMethod2(GridParamsDTO gridParams, CriteriaBuilder builder,
        CriteriaQuery<MyObjectDTO> criteriaQuery, Root<MyObject> from,
        Join<MyObject, AnotherObject> join) {
    if (gridParams.hasSort()) {
        List<Order> orderList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (IGridSort gridSort : gridParams.getSort()) {
            if (ArrayUtils.contains(new String[] { "fieldA", "dateField1", "dateField2", "fieldB" }, gridSort.getField())) {
                if (gridSort.getSort().equalsIgnoreCase(GridSortDTO.ASC)) {
                    orderList.add(builder.asc(from.get(gridSort.getField())));
                } else if (gridSort.getSort().equalsIgnoreCase(GridSortDTO.DESC)) {
                    orderList.add(builder.desc(from.get(gridSort.getField())));
                }
            }
            if (gridSort.getField().equalsIgnoreCase("anotherField")) {
                if (gridSort.getSort().equalsIgnoreCase(GridSortDTO.ASC)) {
                    orderList.add(builder.asc(join.get(AnotherObject_.lib)));
                } else if (gridSort.getSort().equalsIgnoreCase(GridSortDTO.DESC)) {
                    orderList.add(builder.desc(join.get(AnotherObject_.lib)));
                }
            }
        }
        if (!orderList.isEmpty()) {
            criteriaQuery.orderBy(orderList);
        }
    }
    return criteriaQuery;
}

private List<Predicate> subMethod1(GridParamsDTO gridParams, CriteriaBuilder builder,
        List<Predicate> predicates, CriteriaQuery<MyObjectDTO> criteriaQuery, Root<MyObject> from,
        Join<MyObject, AnotherObject> join) {
    if ((gridParams.getFilter() != null) && (gridParams.getFilter().length > 0)) {

        for (final GridFilterDTO filter : gridParams.getFilter()) {
            if ("fieldX".equals(filter.getField())) {
                final List<Predicate> sqPredicates = new ArrayList<>();
                Subquery<Long> sq = criteriaQuery.subquery(Long.class);
                Root<ObjectX> sqFrom = sq.from(ObjectX.class);
                sqPredicates
                        .add(builder.equal(sqFrom.get(ObjectX_.organismeIDE), filter.getFilterSingleValue()));
                sq.select(sqFrom.get(ObjectX_.referentielID).get(MyObject_.objectX));
                sq.where(builder.and(sqPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[sqPredicates.size()])));
                predicates.add(builder.in(from.get(MyObject_.objectX)).value(sq));
            } else if ("fieldA".equals(filter.getField()) || "fieldB".equals(filter.getField())) {
                final GridFilterOperatorEnum gridFilterEnumValues = GridFilterOperatorEnum.values()[filter.getOperator().ordinal()];
                switch (gridFilterEnumValues) {
                case TEXT_CONTAINS:
                    predicates.add(builder.like(builder.upper(from.get(filter.getField())), "%" + filter.getFilterSingleValue().toUpperCase() + "%"));
                    break;
                case TEXT_START_WITH:
                    predicates.add(builder.like(builder.upper(from.get(filter.getField())), filter.getFilterSingleValue().toUpperCase() + "%"));
                    break;
                case TEXT_DIFFERENT:
                    predicates.add(builder.notEqual(from.get(filter.getField()), filter.getFilterSingleValue()));
                    break;
                case TEXT_END_WITH:
                    predicates.add(builder.like(builder.upper(from.get(filter.getField())), "%" + filter.getFilterSingleValue().toUpperCase()));
                    break;
                case TEXT_EQUALS:
                    predicates.add(builder.equal(builder.upper(from.get(filter.getField())), filter.getFilterSingleValue().toUpperCase()));
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            } else if ("dateField1".equals(filter.getField()) || "dateField2".equals(filter.getField())) {
                final GridFilterOperatorEnum gridFilterEnumValues = GridFilterOperatorEnum.values()[filter.getOperator().ordinal()];
                switch (gridFilterEnumValues) {
                case DATE_EQUALS:
                    predicates.add(builder.equal(from.<LocalDate> get(filter.getField()), LocalDate.parse(filter.getFilterSingleValue())));
                    break;
                case DATE_BEFORE:
                    predicates.add(builder.lessThan(from.<LocalDate> get(filter.getField()), LocalDate.parse(filter.getFilterSingleValue())));
                    break;
                case DATE_AFTER:
                    predicates.add(builder.greaterThan(from.<LocalDate> get(filter.getField()), LocalDate.parse(filter.getFilterSingleValue())));
                    break;
                case DATE_BETWEEN:
                    predicates.add(
                            builder.between(from.<LocalDate> get(filter.getField()), LocalDate.parse(filter.getFilterSetValues()[0]),
                                    LocalDate.parse(filter.getFilterSetValues()[1])));
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            } else if ("anotherField".equals(filter.getField())) {
                if (filter.getFilterSetValues().length > 0) {
                    predicates
                            .add(builder.isTrue(join.get(AnotherObject_.lib).in((Object[]) filter.getFilterSetValues())));
                } else {
                    predicates.add(join.get(AnotherObject_.lib).isNull());
                }

            }
        }

    }
    return predicates;
}
```

Comment: What's the point? This code is even less readable than before.

Comment: The Cyclomatic Complexity is the complexity of each method, and counts the number of if/else, loops, operators, exceptions, etc. So if you split the logic of your method you could have a more clean code, probably you could reuse that code for other methods and of course the complexity will decrease.

Comment: I know what cyclomatic complexity is, and I also know its shortcomings (see "cognitive complexity"). Granted the new code effectively reduces cyclomatic complexity. But code quality is more than just raw numbers. The names of the extracted methods could be more expressive. The methods may be extracted differently in a more cohesive/expressive way.

Comment: I just give an example. You should know better what fits best for your case. Just trying to help.